# React native Android loads incorrect code

Tags: android, react-native

When I start my react native App (v0.42.0) on Android it starts with a older version of the code (I simply deleted some parts of the app - they still exist)

On iOS it works correctly.

I started the app with `react-native run-android` `./gradlew assembleDebug && ./gradlew installDebug` and `./gradlew assembleRelease && ./gradlew installRelease. It's always the same bug.

I also deleted the watchman cache, node_modules (plus npm cache), the build folders and restarted my mac.

Another strange thing is if I build the bundle manually with RN cli and set the **DEV** flag true. After installing it, it's set to false (I checked that it's true after building and installing in the code of the bundle)

Is there a way to get it back in a stable state?

Answer (score 0):

Clean the android builder with: `./gradlew clean`

Answer (score 0):

try with this command

```
$ react-native bundle –platform android –dev false –entry-file index.android.js –bundle-output android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle –assets-dest android/app/src/main/res
```

Then,

```
$ react-native run-android
```